# KDB - Ways to overcome limit error through IPC call

Tags: kdb

KDB limit error when calling a large quote table into memory through IPC.

Looking to better structure below query to overcome. Using version 3.3

````
h:hopen....

q) .z.K
(Roundtrip: 078ms)
3.3

q) qtdata:h"select from qtTbl where date=2021.09.22"
(Roundtrip: 00:13.046)
ERROR: 'limit 
(tried to generate a list with more than 2,000,000,000 elements (keep in mind that any IPC result is a byte list, hence can't be longer than 2 metric Gb))```
````

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would try to slice it by time, sym or some other reasonable metric. For example,

```
qtSyms: h"exec sym from select distinct sym from qtTbl where date=2021.09.22";
qtdata: raze h each {select from qtTbl where date=2021.09.22, sym=x},/:qtSyms;

// Less functional, but easier to understand
// raze {h({select from qtTbl where date=2021.09.22, sym=x};x)} each qtSyms
```